# Proof with quantifiers

Tags: logic, proof-verification, quantifiers

$(\forall x)(\exists y)(x+y=0)$ 
$x$ and $y$ are real numbers
The statement reads: for all $x$ there exists some $y$ such that $x+y=0$ is true.
My proof is: take $y=-x$

Is this valid? I'm just paranoid that since the proof is so simple that something is wrong.

Comment: It's simple so as to illustrate the concept. Then, once people have got that, the difficulty increases (to a degree at least).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you've got the right idea:

Simply expand a tad to say:

> Let  $x$ be any arbitrary real number. Then put $y = -x,$ and so $\;x + y = x + - x = 0$. Since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, it holds for *all* $x\in \mathbb R$.